# Unknown provider: ROUTESTATE_CONSTANTProvider <- ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT <- myCtrl

Tags: angularjs

//this is my constant module file
**constant.js**

```
angular.module('constantModule')
.constant('ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT', {
    LOGIN: 'page.login',
    AGENCY_EDIT: 'app.editAgency',
    AGENCY: 'app.agency',
    USER_ADD: 'app.addUser',
    USER: 'app.user',
    BRAND_EDIT: 'app.editBrand',
    BRAND: 'app.brand',
    INTERNATIONAL_COMPANY_EDIT: 'app.editInternationalCompany',
    INTERNATIONAL_COMPANY: 'app.international_company',
    LOCATION_EDIT: 'app.editLocation',
    LOCATION: 'app.location',
    PROJECT: 'app.project',
    PROJECT_EDIT: 'app.editProject',
    PROJECT_ADD: 'app.addProject',
    PRODUCT: 'app.product',
    PRODUCT_EDIT: 'app.editProduct',
    VENDOR: 'app.vendor',
    VENDOR_EDIT: 'app.editVendor',
    PO_EDIT: 'app.editPurchaseOrder',
    PURCHASE_ORDER: 'app.purchase_order',
    CONTRACT : 'app.contract',
    CONTRACT_EDIT: 'app.editContract'
});
```

And this my **app.js** file

```
angular.module('app.lazyload',['oc.lazyLoad'])
.config(function($ocLazyLoadProvider) {
    $ocLazyLoad.load('constantModule');
    return $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
          //debug: true,
          events: true,
          serie:true,
          modules: [{
            name: 'constantModule',
            files: [
              'App/Constants/constant.js'
            ]
          }]
        });
});
angular.module('myconstant.constant', ['constantModule']);


angular.module('MyApp',['ui.router','myconstant.constant'])
.controller('myCtrl',['ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT',function(ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT,{
console.log(ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT);
}]);

angular.element(function(){
    angular.bootstrap(document,['MyApp']);});
```

**i want to load constant module on demand using oclazyload and inject it to the anularjs app for further use. But it is giving me an error 'ROUTESTATE_CONSTANTProvider <- ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT <- myCtrl'.**

Answer (score 0):

Your controller should be ,

```
app.controller("myCtrl", ["$ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT",
    function(ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT) {
    console.log(ROUTESTATE_CONSTANT);
}]);
```